# python: unexplainable infinite recursion with __repr__

Tags: python, debugging, recursion, repr

Here's a piece of code, which goes into an infinite recursion loop, which consists only of `__repr__` function, seemingly calling itself. But I really can't see, how it calls itself. Moreover, I can't even understand, how it was called:

```
class MyList(list): #this is storage for MyDict objects
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyList, self).__init__()

class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, mylist):
        self.mylist = mylist #mydict remembers mylist, to which it belongs
    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self is other
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.mylist.index(self)) #!!!this is the crazy repr, going into recursion
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__repr__())

mylist = MyList()
mydict = MyDict(mylist)
mydict.update({1:2})
print str(mylist.index(mydict)) #here we die :(
```

Execution of this code results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_analogue.py", line 20, in <module>
    print str(mylist.index(mydict))
  File "test_analogue.py", line 13, in __repr__
    return str(self.mylist.index(self))
  File "test_analogue.py", line 13, in __repr__
  ... 
  ... (repetition of last 2 lines for ~666 times)
  ...
  File "test_analogue.py", line 13, in __repr__
    return str(self.mylist.index(self))
  RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Do you understand, how `str(mylist.index(mydict))` managed to call `__repr__`? I'm completely puzzled. Thanks!

Comment: `__repr__` function defined overrides the default `__repr__` which is called by `str(mylist.index(mydict))`. Comment out your `__repr__` function and then see !!!

Comment: @DOOM excuse me, but I can't see, how exactly `str(mylist.index(mydict))` calls `__repr__`. `mylist.index(mydict)` should return an `int`, and `int` should be converted to `str` by `str(<int>)`. Where is `__repr__` here?

Comment: The problem is in the exception that is thrown because `mydict` isn't in `mylist`. The exception tries to get the repr of the dict.

Comment: @kwatford Man, you're right. I'd better take vacations, if I'm gaping on such things. Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>> mylist.index('foo')
ValueError: 'foo' is not in list
```

You never actually added mydict to mylist, so the `index` method tries to raise this error. The error contains the repr of the dict. The repr of the dict, of course, tries to look up its `index` in the list that it isn't in, and this raises an exception, whose error message is calculated using the repr of the dict, which of course, tries to look up its `index` in the list that it isn't in, and...